# How to create SEO Friendly URLs with php server (php.exe)?

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I have a simple local server with php.exe and start server with command prompt:

`php -S localhost:80 -t "web/"`


how do I go in my web browser from urls like:

`localhost/blog.php?id=1`

to seo or user friendly urls:

`localhost/blog/2023/10/01/blog-post`


or from:

`localhost/artist.php?id=1&work=2`

to:

`localhost/artist/Vincent-van-Gogh/art/Sunflowers`


All (video) tutorials on the web are about Apache or Nginx servers, but i want to know specifically how to this with a simple local php server (php.exe).

Comment: Laravel uses [this file](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php) as a server script. If you write something similar (or copy that one, it is under the MIT licence) you can probably run it as `php -S localhost:80 -t "web/" server.php`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, note that the built-in web server is intended for *development and testing purposes only*. It should not be used as the primary way of serving a website, as it is not designed with the necessary security, performance, or stability.

Secondly, it's important to understand that you can't really "make a URL pretty"; what you can do is *tell the server how to respond to a pretty URL*. That means you can make pretty URLs do the same as ugly URLs, but looking at it the right way around stops you trying to do the impossible, like making one URL do two things, or serve a URL that doesn't include the information your code needs.

With that in mind, [the PHP documentation for the built-in server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) gives a very simple example of a "router script" - something that looks at the URL requested, and decides what to do with it. That's the script that you need to write, and you can basically do it however you want. You then provide the path to that script as an extra argument when running php.exe, like `php -S localhost:8000 router.php`

If you use a framework like Laravel, Symfony, CakePHP, Laminas, etc, that script will be provided for you. Or you can find a library for the purpose like [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute). But in the end, these are all just ways to define a bunch of if statements: "if the URL matches this pattern, run this function with these arguments" or "if the URL matches this pattern, set up this data then include that file".